# Is it possible to run multiple startup script with systemd at startup with Beaglebone Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, systemd, beagleboneblack

I was referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431674/post-install-script-on-yocto-built-linux) to create startup script in BeagleBone Yocto, I have 3 scenario required to run in startup. I am not really sure what is best way to do it, should I create 3 services and have them pointing 3 different script or is it possible to launch multiple script in one service. What I mean is something shown below in my service file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=RUNNING BUILD IN TESTING SCRIPT

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5 ; /usr/sbin/check_emmc.sh'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5 ; /usr/sbin/blinkled.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, this method only work one script, is it possible to make one service to run multiple shell script?

Comment: What the problem to put them in one `ExecStart` line as a shell script itself? Something like `sh -c ' scriptA &; scriptB &; ...'`.

Comment: Is there a strong relationship between these services ? If no, in my opinion it's better to separate them.

Comment: @0andriy ya, nothing wrong with that, just that i really new on the linux  thingy, thanks for your input

Comment: I would suggest using separate services per script - this will allow you to filter logs in future, also you can delay startup as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44737570